# sort part of a file

Tags: text-processing, sort

How can I sort the file by the second column from the terminal. The content of the file is:

```
Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Sunday   20
Others   10
Shnou    5
```

Using `sort -t' ' -nk2` is not giving me the right result. Also how can I ensure that the content of the file stay sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like these:

#### Method #1: using head & tail

```
$ (head -n 2 sample.txt; tail -n +3 sample.txt | sort -t' ' -nk2) > a.tmp && mv a.tmp sample.txt

Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Shnou    5
Others   10
Sunday   20
```

This takes the first line of the text file, then tails everything after the first 2 lines which is then sorted.

#### Method #2: just using head

```
$ (head -n 2; sort -t' ' -nk2) < sample.txt > a.tmp && mv a.tmp sample.txt

Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Shnou    5
Others   10
Sunday   20
```

Takes the text file as input, displays just the first line, sort the rest.

It's typically not a good idea to edit files in place. It's possible, but better to use an intermediate file.

#### Method #3: Doing #2 without an intermediate file

Stealing the idea from @StephaneChazelas you could do the following using the "1<>" notation to open a file for reading & writing, and the improvements he suggested with the `sort` command.

```
$ (head -n 2; sort -nk2) < sample.txt 1<> sample.txt

Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Shnou    5
Others   10
Sunday   20
```

Comment: but the file remains unchanged, do I have to use an intermediate file?

Comment: the file became empty

Comment: Try them now, I opted to use intermediate files.

Comment: I think it is better to use `head -2` and include the dashed lines as part of the head. They get sorted correctly now but that is probably not the case when using a separator like `= = = =` ( `'=' > '9' > '-'` ).

Comment: @Anthon, good point.

Answer (score 7):

To overwrite the file in place, you can do:

```
{
  head -n 2 &&
    sort -k2n
} < the-file.txt 1<> the-file.txt
```

That works because `sort` has read its input fully before it starts to write its output, so it's fine to write to the file it is reading from. Also its ouput is the same size as its input, so no need to truncate the file in the end.

Note that if you use `-t' '` instead of the default separator, each space character in the input would make a new field, so for instance in:

```
 a 10
b  2
```

(with a space before `a` and 2 spaces after `b`), `-t' ' -nk2` (remember `-k2` is for *from field 2 to end of line*, while `-k2,2` is *field 2 only*) would compare `"a 10"` to `" 2"` numerically, while `-nk2` alone would compare `" 10"` to `"  2"` numerically (and numerical comparison ignores leading blanks).

Comment: You're gonna have to explain that magic 8-)

Comment: I get the { } is a list. What's going on with the 1<>.

Comment: `1<>` is Bourne read-write redirection, one of the standard redirection operators like `<` and `>`.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the man page after I asked. Learned something new today. Never noticed that method.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to sort 2 parts of one file.
Significantly inspired by the other answers, here is an extended answer:

**file.txt**

```
Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Sunday   20
Others   10
Shnou    5

Example
------------
Foo
bar
Baz

Results: Finished!
```

Multiple sections can be chained and sorted or not with varying options.
Use `cat` as the last step to output any unsorted chunks at the end.

```
(head -n 2; head -n 4 | sort -nk2 ; head -n 3; head -n 3 | sort; cat ) < file.txt 1<> sorted.txt
```

**sorted.txt**

```
Nome     Note
------------
Mehdi    0
Shnou    5
Others   10
Sunday   20

Example
------------
bar
Baz
Foo

Results: Finished!
```

Comment: I tested this under macOS and Linux (18.04) and this concept of sequential programs getting the "leftover" output from `head` only seems to work on the Linux machine. On macOS, this works in neither zsh nor bash; only the first two lines appear in the sorted.txt. Furthermore, on macOS because I do have GNU coreutils installed via home-brew, replacing all `head` calls with `ghead` *did work*. It looks like `BSD head` simply isn't doing the thing that allows this method to work. I am not sure why, though. I hope someone can step in and explain what shell I/O concept is at play here.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the concept of not "blackhole"-ing the stdin stream. I've definitely noticed that some commands you can type into while they are running and what you typed becomes interpreted by the shell afterwards, you may even chain many of these commands, and as long as those commands do not "black hole" the stdin, the shell will dutifully run them as sequential commands because they "spill over". So in that vein the BSD `head` appears to blackhole its stdin, whereas GNU `head` only slurps up the number of lines you specify to it, leaving the rest be.